# Get certain amount from enum

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum and I want to get some info from it.
this is the enum:

```
public static enum Prayer {
        THICK_SKIN(new double[] {21233, 1, 83, 12}, DEFENCE_PRAYER, false),
        BURST_OF_STRENGTH(new double[] {21234, 4, 84, 12}, STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        CLARITY_OF_THOUGHT(new double[] {21235, 7, 85, 12}, ATTACK_PRAYER, false),
        ROCK_SKIN(new double[] {21236, 10, 86, 6}, DEFENCE_PRAYER, false),
        SUPERHUMAN_STRENGTH(new double[] {21237, 13, 87, 6}, STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        IMPROVED_REFLEXES(new double[] {21238, 16, 88, 6}, ATTACK_PRAYER, false),
        RAPID_RESTORE(new double[] {21239, 19, 89, 26}, -1, false),
        RAPID_HEAL(new double[] {21240, 22, 90, 18}, -1, false),
        PROTECT_ITEM(new double[] {25020, 25, 91, 18}, -1, false),
        STEEL_SKIN(new double[] {21242, 28, 92, 3}, DEFENCE_PRAYER, false),
        ULTIMATE_STRENGTH(new double[] {21243, 31, 93, 3}, STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        INCREDIBLE_REFLEXES(new double[] {21244, 34, 94, 3}, ATTACK_PRAYER, false),
        PROTECT_FROM_MAGIC(new double[] {21245, 37, 95, 3, 2}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, false),
        PROTECT_FROM_MISSILES(new double[] {21246, 40, 96, 3, 1}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, false),
        PROTECT_FROM_MELEE(new double[] {21247, 43, 97, 3, 0}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, false),
        RETRIBUTION(new double[] {2171, 46, 98, 1, 3}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, false),
        REDEMPTION(new double[] {2172, 49, 99, 2, 5}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, false),
        SMITE(new double[] {2173, 52, 100, 2, 4}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, false),
        SHARP_EYE(new double[] {70080, 8, 601, 12}, RANGE_PRAYER | ATTACK_PRAYER | STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        MYSTIC_WILL(new double[] {70082, 9, 602, 12}, MAGIC_PRAYER | ATTACK_PRAYER | STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        HAWK_EYE(new double[] {70084, 26, 603, 6}, RANGE_PRAYER | ATTACK_PRAYER | STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        MYSTIC_LORE(new double[] {70086, 27, 604, 6}, MAGIC_PRAYER | ATTACK_PRAYER | STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        EAGLE_EYE(new double[] {70088, 44, 605, 3}, RANGE_PRAYER | ATTACK_PRAYER | STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        MYSTIC_MIGHT(new double[] {70090, 45, 606, 3}, MAGIC_PRAYER | ATTACK_PRAYER | STRENGTH_PRAYER, false),
        CHIVALRY(new double[] {70092, 60, 607, 1.5}, ATTACK_PRAYER | STRENGTH_PRAYER | DEFENCE_PRAYER, false),
        PIETY(new double[] {70094, 70, 608, 1.5}, ATTACK_PRAYER | STRENGTH_PRAYER | DEFENCE_PRAYER, false),
        PROTECT_ITEM_(new double[] {87231, 50, 83, 18, 12567, 2213}, -1, true),
        SAP_WARRIOR(new double[] {87233, 50, 84, 2.57}, SAP_PRAYER, true),
        SAP_RANGER(new double[] {87235, 52, 85, 2.57}, SAP_PRAYER, true),
        SAP_MAGE(new double[] {87237, 54, 101, 2.57}, SAP_PRAYER, true),
        SAP_SPIRIT(new double[] {87239, 56, 102, 2.57}, SAP_PRAYER, true),
        BERSERKER(new double[] {87241, 59, 86, 18, 12589, 2266}, -1, true),
        DEFLECT_SUMMON(new double[] {87243, 62, 87, 3}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, true),
        DEFLECT_MAGIC(new double[] {87245, 65, 88, 3, 10}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, true),
        DEFLECT_RANGE(new double[] {87247, 68, 89, 3, 11}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, true),
        DEFLECT_MELEE(new double[] {87249, 71, 90, 3, 9}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, true),
        LEECH_ATTACK(new double[] {87251, 74, 91, 3}, LEECH_PRAYER, true),
        LEECH_RANGE(new double[] {87253, 76, 103, 3}, LEECH_PRAYER, true),
        LEECH_MAGE(new double[] {87255, 78, 104, 3}, LEECH_PRAYER, true),
        LEECH_DEFENCE(new double[] {88001, 80, 92, 3}, LEECH_PRAYER, true),
        LEECH_STRENGTH(new double[] {88003, 82, 93, 3}, LEECH_PRAYER, true),
        LEECH_ENERGY(new double[] {88005, 84, 94, 3.6}, LEECH_PRAYER, true),
        LEECH_SPECIAL(new double[] {88007, 86, 95, 3}, LEECH_PRAYER, true),
        WRATH(new double[] {88009, 89, 96, 12, 16}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, true),
        SOUL_SPLIT(new double[] {88011, 92, 97, 2, 17}, OVERHEAD_PRAYER, true),
        TURMOIL(new double[] {88013, 95, 105, 2, 12565, 2226}, SAP_PRAYER | LEECH_PRAYER, true);
```

Here is some codes to know what everything means:

```
private Prayer(double[] data, int prayerMask, boolean curse) {
            this.id = (int) data[0];
            this.level = (int) data[1];
            this.config = (int) data[2];
            this.drain = data[3] * 2;
            this.icon = (int) (data.length == 5 ? data[4] : -1);
            this.anim = data.length == 6 ? (int) data[4] : -1;
            this.graphic = data.length == 6 ? (int) data[5] : -1;
            this.name = Misc.formatPlayerName(this.toString());
            this.prayMask = prayerMask;
            this.curse = curse;
        }
...
public double getDrain() {
            return drain;
        }
```

I want to get the fourth number every time. It has to be in a form like this, but this doesn't work:

```
public void handlePrayerDrain() {
        double toRemove = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < prayerData.length; j++) {
            if (c.prayerActive[j]) {
                toRemove += prayerData[j]/20;
            }
        }
        if (toRemove > 0) {
            toRemove /= (1 + (0.035 * c.playerBonus[11]));      
        }
        c.prayerPoint -= toRemove;
        if (c.prayerPoint <= 0) {
            c.prayerPoint = 1.0 + c.prayerPoint;
            reducePrayerLevel();
        }

    }
```

Explanation: What I exactly want to happen is that the `handlePrayerDrain` method gets the length of the enum (`for (int j = 0; j < prayerData.length; j++) {`) and after that it checks which one are on (`if (c.prayerActive[j]) {`) and after that it checks what the drain amount is (`toRemove += prayerData[j]/20;`)

This is some code in my Client.java (if this helps):

```
private ArrayList<Prayers.Prayer> activePrayers = new ArrayList<Prayers.Prayer>();

public ArrayList<Prayers.Prayer> getActivePrayers() {
    return activePrayers;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `prayerData`? What is the type of `c`? What is the type of `c.prayerActive`? What does the constructor for `Prayer` look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over all possible values of the enum, try:

```
for (Prayer p : Prayer.values()) {
    // your logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 then streams provide a fairly neat way of summing some value from an `enum`. While it's a bit hard to tell exactly what you want to do, here is a similar example that might give you what you want (I think:-)).

```
enum Prayer {
    ...
    public double getCost();
}

class Player {
    ...
    public boolean hasActivePrayer(Prayer prayer);
}

double toRemove = Arrays.stream(Prayer.values())
    .filter(player.getActivePrayer()::contains)
    .mapToDouble(Prayer::getDrain)
    .sum() / 10;

...
```

Comment: i have added some code from my Client.java and Prayer.java to my main question and I think that getCost is getDrain, right?

Comment: Can you get into a bit more detail wit hthe new snippets I have added to my main post?

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx I'm happy to convert to your structures but it's still unclear to me what `c.prayerActive` is. I'm assuming it's an array of booleans but it's hard to tell from the snippets you've added. Could you include your declaration of `c`?

Comment: c.prayerActive doesn't exist anymore, but I need to use: getActivePrayers().contains(Prayer.PRAYERNAMEHERE) if you put a prayer name there it's only for one prayer, ofcourse, but I want it to check it for all prayers in the enum. c is a reference to Client.java and Client.java has all kinds of links to other classes, so if you have a boolean called: hasItem in player.java you can just use c(lient).hasItem

Comment: I fixed it with using:
`for (Prayer p : Prayer.values()) {
   if (c.getActivePrayers().contains(p)) {
    toRemove += p.getDrain() / 10;
   }
  }`